# change the page scale (ctrl+ ctrl-), is breaking the page layout

Tags: html, css

When I change the page scale (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>+</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>-</kbd>), is breaking the page layout.

The last item is falling down.

Help me that I need to change in layout to the menu properly scaled.

- Page:
- Screenshot:

Comment: Which browser? For me, testing in Chrome, the problem only happens when I *zoom out*. Virtually nobody will zoom out your site.

Comment: FF, IE, Chrome..
Yes, the problem happens when I zoom out.
The goal is to scaling all was ok.
Thanks.

Comment: What I was saying is that your problem is *not actually a problem*, other than satisfying perfectionism.

Comment: Thank you Thirtydot and Andrei Bodnarescu, I will follow your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it seems to really matter to you, here's an idea.

Try replacing `float: left` on the menu items with `display:inline-block` (or `display:inline-block;*display:inline;zoom:1` if you need IE7 support) and `white-space: nowrap` on the parent element.

You'll also have to remove some whitespace in the HTML:

```
</li>

<li class="level1" id="pm2"><a href="/computers/" class="level1">..</a>
```

to:

```
</li><li class="level1" id="pm2"><a href="/computers/" class="level1">..</a>
```

And the same for the rest.

Once you're done, it should look identical, but the zooming "problem" should be fixed.

Comment: Thank you Thirtydot, I will follow your advice.

Comment: Hi.
I took your advice. Look at the result.
http://copy.protoria.com.ua/newnav/
I have a new question.
As you can see our menu items can be either one or two lines.
How to align vertically items one or two lines.
Your recommendations.


Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a look at your page. I don't have time to play with the code right now, but how about you replace those menu items from `<ul> <li>.... </ul>` with each `<li>` having a float:left css to something that can give you the same layout without using the float:left (like a `<table>`)? The float:left is not good for when page is scaled AFAIK

Comment: I thought about to use a table to a horizontal menu. Perhaps you have on hand is a link to the working examples.
Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Ok look, I'm not gonna redo your html for you, that's a lot of stuff there. But look, I've tried some basic table stuff and it looks promising, now if I zoom in or out a lot everything's still aligned.

Here's what you should try:

In your html page code you have a `<ul id="protoria_menu">` which contains all your upper horizontal menu (as `<li>...</li>` elements). Replace the ul with table, add righ bellow it a `<tr>`, then change each main `<li>....</li>` element to `<td>...</td>`. This way you'll have your menu in a table with one row and multiple columns.

Something like this:

```
<table id="protoria_menu">
<tr>
<td id="pm1" class="level1"><a class="level1" href="/laptops-accessories/">Ноутбуки</a>
    <div class="pm-dropdown">
    <ul class="pm-primary">
        <li><a href="/laptops-accessories/laptops/"><strong>Ноутбуки</strong></a></li>
        <li><a href="/laptops-accessories/tablet/"><strong>Интернет-планшеты</strong></a></li>
        <li><a href="/apple/ipad/"><strong>Apple iPad</strong></a></li>
        <li><a href="/laptops-accessories/sceys/">Сумки и чехлы</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="pm-secondary">
        <li><a href="/laptops-accessories/soft/">Программное обеспечение</a></li>
        <li><a href="/laptops-accessories/accessories/">Аксессуары</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/laptops-accessories/accessories/p2609v3522/p2609v3523">USB кабели и адаптеры</a></li>
                <li><a href="/laptops-accessories/accessories/p2609v3478">Аккумуляторы</a></li>
                <li><a href="/laptops-accessories/accessories/p2609v3471">Блоки питания</a></li>
                <li><a href="/laptops-accessories/accessories/p2609v3474">Подставки</a></li>
                <li><a href="/laptops-accessories/accessories/">все аксессуары …</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/apple/apple-accessories/p1885v2721">Аксессуары к APPLE</a></li>
        <!-- li><a href="#">Гаджеты к APPLE</a></li -->
        <li><a href="/computers/mouse/">Клавиатуры, мыши, коврики</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/computers/mouse/p1411v3519/p1411v3570">Клавиатуры</a></li>
                <li><a href="/computers/mouse/p1411v3519/p1411v3554">Мыши</a></li>
        <li><a href="/computers/mouse/">все клавиатуры, мыши, <br>коврики …</a>
            </li></ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/computers/external-hdd/">Внешние HDD</a></li>
        <li><a href="/computers/external-hard-drives-ssd/">SSD накопители</a></li>
        <li><a href="/computers/flash/">USB flash накопители</a></li>
        <li><a href="/computers/clener/">Средства по уходу</a></li>
        <li><a href="/laptops-accessories/mobileinternet/">Мобильный интернет</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</li>
<li id="pm2" class="level1"><a class="level1" href="/computers/">Компьютеры</a>
    <div class="pm-dropdown">
    <ul class="pm-primary">
        <li><a href="/computers/monoblock/"><strong>Моноблоки</strong></a></li>
        <li><a href="/computers/desktops/"><strong>Компьютеры</strong></a></li>
        <li><a href="/computers/displays/"><strong>Мониторы</strong></a></li>
        <li><a href="/computers/external-hdd/">Внешние HDD</a></li>
        <li><a href="/computers/external-hard-drives-ssd/">SSD накопители</a></li>
        <li><a href="/computers/flash/">USB flash накопители</a></li>
        <li><a href="/computers/nas/">Сетевые накопители (NAS)</a></li>
        <li><a href="/computers/networking/">Сетевое оборудование</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="pm-secondary">
        <li><a href="/computers/mouse/">Клавиатуры, мыши, коврики</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/computers/mouse/p1411v3519/p1411v3570">Клавиатуры</a></li>
                <li><a href="/computers/mouse/p1411v3519/p1411v3554">Мыши</a></li>
        <li><a href="/computers/mouse/">все клавиатуры, мыши, <br>коврики …</a>
            </li></ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/computers/akustiks/">Акустические системы</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/computers/akustiks/p1429v1054">5.1</a></li>
                <li><a href="/computers/akustiks/p1429v1055">2.1</a></li>
                <li><a href="/computers/akustiks/p1429v1056">2.0</a></li>
                <li><a href="/computers/akustiks/">вся акустика …</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/computers/webkamers/">Веб-камеры</a></li>
        <li><a href="/computers/naushniki/">Гарнитуры и микрофоны</a></li>
        <li><a href="/gadgets-electronics/pentablets/">Графические планшеты</a></li>
        <li><a href="/computers/ups/">Источники бесперебойного питания</a></li>
        <li><a href="/computers/philters/">Сетевые фильтры</a></li>
        <li><a href="/computers/clener/">Средства по уходу</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</li>
<li id="pm3" class="level1"><a class="level1" href="/component-parts/">Компьютерные<br>комплектующие</a>
    <div class="pm-dropdown">
    <ul class="pm-primary">
        <li><a href="/component-parts/case/">Корпуса</a></li>
        <li><a href="/component-parts/processors/">Процессоры</a></li>
        <li><a href="/component-parts/videocard/">Видеокарты</a></li>
        <li><a href="/component-parts/sound-card/">Звуковые карты</a></li>
        <li><a href="/component-parts/mp/">Материнские платы</a></li>
        <li><a href="/component-parts/mem/">Модули памяти</a></li>
        <li><a href="/component-parts/hdd/">Жесткие Диски</a></li>
        <li><a href="/component-parts/ssd-drives/">Диски SSD</a></li>
        <li><a href="/component-parts/powersupply/">Блоки питания</a></li>
        <li><a href="/component-parts/cooler/">Системы охлаждения</a></li>
        <li><a href="/component-parts/odd/">Дисководы DVD, CD, Blu-ray</a></li>
        <li><a href="/computers/networking/">Сетевое оборудование</a></li>
        <li><a href="/computers/desktops/">Системные блоки в сборе</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</li>
<li id="pm4" class="level1"><a class="level1" href="/kompsperef/">Оргтехника</a>
    <div class="pm-dropdown">
    <ul class="pm-primary">
        <li><a href="/kompsperef/mfu/"><strong>МФУ</strong></a></li>
        <li><a href="/kompsperef/printers/">Принтеры струйные и лазерные</a>
    <ul>
                <li><a href="/kompsperef/printers/p122v198">Монохромный</a></li>
                <li><a href="/kompsperef/printers/p122v199">Цветной</a></li>
                <li><a href="/kompsperef/printers/p122v200">Фотопринтер</a></li>
                <li><a href="/kompsperef/printers/">все принтеры …</a></li>
    </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/tvbidaud/proektoru/">Проекторы</a></li>
        <li><a href="/kompsperef/fax/">Факсы</a></li>
        <li><a href="/kompsperef/skaners/">Сканеры</a></li>
        <li><a href="/kompsperef/corded-phones/">Проводные телефоны</a></li>
        <li><a href="/kompsperef/cordless-phones/">Радиотелефоны</a></li>
        <li><a href="/kompsperef/kartridj/">Картриджи</a></li>
        <li><a href="/kompsperef/bumaga/">Бумага</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</li>
<li id="pm5" class="level1"><a class="level1" href="/telefsmart/">Смартфоны,<br>телефоны</a>
    <div class="pm-dropdown">
    <ul class="pm-primary">
        <li><a href="/telefsmart/mobile/p424v477"><strong>Смартфоны</strong></a></li>
        <li><a href="/telefsmart/mobile/"><strong>Мобильные телефоны</strong></a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="pm-secondary">
        <li><a href="/telefsmart/covers/">Сумки, чехлы</a></li>
        <li><a href="/telefsmart/zum/">Зарядные устройства</a></li>
        <li><a href="/telefsmart/makom/">Аккумуляторы</a></li>
        <li><a href="/photovideo/cartsmem/">Карты памяти</a></li>
        <li><a href="/telefsmart/hendsfree/">Гарнитуры</a></li>
        <li><a href="/telefsmart/mobileakses/">Другие аксессуары</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</li>
<li id="pm6" class="level1"><a class="level1" href="/photovideo/">Фото</a>
    <div class="pm-dropdown">
    <ul class="pm-primary">
        <li><a href="/photovideo/slr/"><strong>Фотокамеры со сменной оптикой</strong></a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/photovideo/slr/p2664v3629">Зеркальные</a></li>
                <li><a href="/photovideo/slr/p2664v3630">Беззеркальные</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/photovideo/photoaparats/"><strong>Компактные фотоаппараты</strong></a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/photovideo/photoaparats/p329v425">Компактные</a></li>
                <li><a href="/photovideo/photoaparats/p329v378">Ультра-компактные</a></li>
                <li><a href="/photovideo/photoaparats/p329v426">Длиннофокусные</a></li>
        <!-- li><a href="/photovideo/photoaparats/">Все компактные фотоаппараты &hellip;</a></li -->
            </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="pm-secondary">
        <li><a href="/photovideo/lensesandfilters/">Объективы</a></li>
        <li><a href="/photovideo/flash/">Вспышки</a></li>
        <li><a href="/photovideo/filters/">Светофильтры</a></li>
        <li><a href="/photovideo/shtativ/">Штативы</a></li>
        <!-- li><a href="#">Гаджеты к фото</a></li -->
        <li><a href="/photovideo/photosumki/">Сумки</a></li>
        <li><a href="/photovideo/cartsmem/">Карты памяти</a></li>
        <li><a href="/photovideo/photovideoakum/">Аккумуляторы, зарядные устройства и батарейки</a></li>
        <li><a href="/photovideo/photokamersakses/">Аксессуары и средства по уходу</a></li>
        <li><a href="/kompsperef/printers/p122v200">Фотопринтеры</a></li>
        <li><a href="/photovideo/videokamers/">Видеокамеры</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</li>
<li id="pm7" class="level1"><a class="level1" href="/gadgets-electronics/">Гаджеты</a>
    <div class="pm-dropdown">
    <ul class="pm-primary">
        <li><a href="/gadgets-electronics/e-books/"><strong>Электронные книги</strong></a></li>
        <li><a href="/gadgets-electronics/ipodmp3/"><strong>MP3 плееры</strong></a></li>
        <li><a href="/gadgets-electronics/digital-picture-frames/"><strong>Цифровые фоторамки</strong></a></li>
        <li><a href="/gadgets-electronics/gps/"><strong>GPS навигация</strong></a></li>
        <li><a href="/apple/ipod/"><strong>iPod</strong></a></li>
        <li><a href="/gadgets-electronics/pentablets/">Графические планшеты</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="pm-secondary">
        <!-- li><a href="#">Аксессуары к книгам и планшетам</a></li -->
        <li><a href="/gadgets-electronics/gpsaccesories/">Аксессуары к GPS</a></li>
        <li><a href="/gadgets-electronics/headphones/">Наушники</a></li>
        <li><a href="/gadgets-electronics/3d-acces/">3D аксессуары</a></li>
        <li><a href="/apple/apple-accessories/">Аксессуары к APPLE</a></li>
        <li><a href="/apple/gadgets-for-apple/">Гаджеты к APPLE</a></li>
        <li><a href="/gadgets-electronics/meteo/">Погодные станции, часы и радио </a></li>
        <li><a href="/gadgets-electronics/port-dvd/">Портативные DVD плееры </a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</li>
<li id="pm8" class="level1"><a class="level1" href="/tvbidaud/">Телевизоры<br>и видео</a>
    <div class="pm-dropdown">
   <ul class="pm-primary">
        <li><a href="/tvbidaud/lcd-led/"><strong>Телевизоры</strong></a></li>
        <li><a href="/tvbidaud/proektoru/"><strong>Проекторы</strong></a></li>
        <li><a href="/tvbidaud/ekranu/">Экраны</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="pm-secondary">
        <li><a href="/tvbidaud/3d-aksessuary/">3D аксессуары к ТВ</a></li>
        <li><a href="/tvbidaud/hdtv-mediaplayers/">HDTV медиаплееры</a></li>
        <li><a href="/tvbidaud/dvd-blu-ray-players/">DVD/Blu-ray плееры</a></li>
        <li><a href="/tvbidaud/kabeli-podkljchenija/">Кабели для ТВ</a></li>
        <li><a href="/tvbidaud/kreplenija-dlya-tv-av-projectorov/">Крепления для TV, AV и проекторов</a></li>
        <li><a href="/tvbidaud/acses/">Аксессуары и средства по уходу</a></li>
        <li><a href="/tvbidaud/domawnie-kinoteatru/">Домашние кинотеатры</a></li>
        <li><a href="/tvbidaud/akysticheskie-sistemu/">Музыкальные центры и HI-FI </a></li>
        <li><a href="/tvbidaud/tymbu-i-podstavki/">Тумбы и подставки</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</li>
<li id="pm9" class="level1"><a class="level1" href="/pristavki/">Игровая<br>зона</a>
    <div class="pm-dropdown">
    <ul class="pm-primary">
        <li><a href="/pristavki/gamebox/"><strong>Игровые приставки</strong></a></li>
        <li><a href="/pristavki/gameboxgames/">Игровые аксессуары</a></li>
        <li><a href="/pristavki/joystick/">Игровые манипуляторы</a></li>
        <li><a href="/computers/mouse/p2649v3571">Геймерские мышки и клавиатуры</a></li>
        <li><a href="/pristavki/games/">Игры</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</li>
<li id="pm10" class="level1"><a class="level1" href="/apple/">APPLE</a>
    <div class="pm-dropdown">
    <ul class="pm-primary">
        <li><a href="/apple/macbook/"><strong>MacBook</strong></a></li>
        <li><a href="/apple/ipod/"><strong>iPod</strong></a></li>
        <li><a href="/apple/ipad/"><strong>iPad</strong></a></li>
        <li><a href="/apple/apple-accessories/">Аксессуары к APPLE</a></li>
        <li><a href="/apple/gadgets-for-apple/">Гаджеты к APPLE</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</li>
```

Look, it seems to work:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you Andrei Bodnarescu, I will follow your advice.